# LuaLaTeX KOMA scrlttr2 without E-Mail:

Tags: preamble, scrlttr2, email

I made a letter with `scrlttr2` KOMA script and activated `fromemail=on` but that brings up the pre E-Mail: in the line of the email that looks like this: `E-Mail: adress@url.tld`.

Now I don't like the pre `E-Mail:` there. Can it be set off somehow?

Comment: How about showing us the code (without personal informations!) you used?  Then it is much easier to help you ...  Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear if you want no E-mail there or just a symbol.  However, the following MWE shows you how you can change the text:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  paper=a4,
  parskip=half,
  enlargefirstpage=on,    % More space on first page
  fromalign=right,        % PLacement of name in letter head
  fromphone=on,           % Turn on phone number of sender
  fromrule=aftername,     % Rule after sender name in letter head
  fromemail=true,         % <===========================================
  addrfield=on,           % Adress field for envelope with window
  backaddress=on,         % Sender address in this window
  subject=beforeopening,  % Placement of subject
  locfield=narrow,        % Additional field for sender
  foldmarks=on,           % Print foldmarks
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \LARGE}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Musterfrau}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Musterstrasse 9,\\12345 Ort}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49\,12\,34\,56\,789}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{max.musterfrau@web.de} 
\setkomavar{signature}{(Max Musterfrau)}
\setkomavar{place}{Ort}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\usepackage{marvosym} % <================================================

\begin{document}
\renewcaptionname{english}\emailname{\Email} % <=========================
\renewcaptionname{english}\phonename{\Telefon} % <=======================
\begin{letter}{To: Claire Laterfield}
\setkomavar{subject}{Greetings}
\opening{Dear Claire,}
I am writing this letter because I have nothing better to do.

\closing{Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Important are the lines in the code marked with `% <===========`.

Package `marvosym` loads the symbols for email etc. With `\renewcaptionname` you can advice KOMA-Script to use the given symbols instead of the text.

The resulting pdf is:

[image]

Without having a symbol or a text for email etc. you have to change the code in the following way: Change the text/symbol to `~` (Blank), change the separator to `~` too: `\setkomavar{emailseparator}{~}`.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  paper=a4,
  parskip=half,
  enlargefirstpage=on,    % More space on first page
  fromalign=right,        % PLacement of name in letter head
  fromphone=on,           % Turn on phone number of sender
  fromrule=aftername,     % Rule after sender name in letter head
  fromemail=true,         % <===========================================
  addrfield=on,           % Adress field for envelope with window
  backaddress=on,         % Sender address in this window
  subject=beforeopening,  % Placement of subject
  locfield=narrow,        % Additional field for sender
  foldmarks=on,           % Print foldmarks
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \LARGE}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Musterfrau}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Musterstrasse 9\\12345 Ort}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49\,12\,34\,56\,789}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{max.musterfrau@web.de} 
\setkomavar{signature}{(Max Musterfrau)}
\setkomavar{place}{Ort}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
%\usepackage{marvosym} % <================================================
\setkomavar{phoneseparator}{~} % <========================================
\setkomavar{emailseparator}{~} % <========================================

\begin{document}
\renewcaptionname{english}\emailname{~} % <=========================
\renewcaptionname{english}\phonename{~} % <=======================
\begin{letter}{To: Claire Laterfield}
\setkomavar{subject}{Greetings}
\opening{Dear Claire,}
I am writing this letter because I have nothing better to do.

\closing{Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

you get the wanted result:

[image]

Comment: Thats interessting! 
Its almost what i whant but i wold prefer to leave out the envelope or "E-Mail:" fully.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is actually quite easy and can be achieved without tampering with the `emailseparator` or redefining `\emailname`.

As you can see in the documentation table 4.7 the default description for the `fromemail` variable is `\usekomavar*{emailseparator}\usekomavar{emailseparator}`. That description compiles to the "E-Mail: " you are seeing.

The easiest way to change this description is to provide on when setting the koma variable. So instead of `\setkomavar{fromemail}{info@example.com}` you simply need to write `\setkomavar{fromemail}[]{info@example.com}`