# LuaLaTeX scrlttr2 letterbody indent Text

Tags: indentation, koma-script, letterspacing, subjective

I found a section describing the `letterbody` in the manual but no advice how to position the section horizontal.

The problem is that with the [workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342029/lualatex-koma-scrlttr2-without-e-mail?noredirect=1#comment839228_342029) to make the Text "Betreff:" or "E-Mail:" go I insert some kind of spaces that now don't aline with the `letterbody`. So eather to indent the `letterbody` or horizontaly aline the `subject` section would help but both I can not find.

My letter has 175 lines now so I don't post it... [here is a pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/U0D6zb5T)

Comment: Please add a screenshot and mark there which part of the letter is not "aline".  And please add MWE directly on this page, do not use a link to another webpage, if possible ...

Answer (score 1):

You need---if I understand you correctly---to change the subjectseparator from a blank to no sign, for example by using the command: `\setkomavar{subjectseparator}{}`

Then the subject will not be indented.  See the following compiling MWE (code change marked with `<=========`):

```
%%Brief-Vorlage, v1.03
%%kompiliert mit LuaTeX
\documentclass[%
    fontsize=12pt,          % fontsize
    paper=a4,               % page size a4
    firsthead=on,           % display header on first page
    headsepline=false,
    fromalign=right,         % placement of name in letter head | centered,
    fromrule=false,  % separate the address with a line in letter head, false or aftername, afteraddress
    fromemail=on,          % turn on email of sender
    fromurl=off,            % print URL of sender
    fromphone=false,          % turn on phone of sender
    fromlogo=on,           % turn on logo of sender    
    fromfax=false,
    backaddress=off,
    subject=afteropening,        %beforeopening <===============================
    %subject=underlined,
    subject=titled,         % untitled
    subject=left,               % centered
    locfield=wide,          % wide, narrow
    refline=wide,               % narrow
    parskip=half,           % Use indent instead of skip, half, false
    enlargefirstpage=on,    % more space on first page
    addrfield=on,           % address field for envelope with window, on or true
    subject=titled,         % placement of subject, beforeopening or titled
    foldmarks=on,          % print foldmarks
    numericaldate=off,      % display date in numbers only
    footsepline=false,  
    firstfoot=on,           % display footer on first page
    pagenumber=botleft,         % position of the page number | botcenter,        
    draft=false
 ]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant = swiss]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant = british]{english}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{showframe} % <==============================================

% Fontspec
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
%%\setmainfont{Gill Sans Light}
%%\setsansfont{Gill Sans Light}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
%%\setmonofont{Inconsolata}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
%%\setmathfont{XITS-Math}[]
%\setmathsf{}[]
%\setmathtt{}[]
%\setboldmathrm{}[]
\definecolor{grau}{rgb}{0.20,0.40,0.65}

% Development helpers
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\LoadLetterOption{SNleft} %% oder: DINmtext, SN, SNleft, KOMAold.
%\LoadLetterOption{visualize}\showfields{address,foot,head,location,refline}    % loads visualize.lco to visualize boxes
\fboxrule=0pt                                           %border thickness der fboxes zum bearbeiten auf 1 setzten

% KOMA blockgrössen
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
  \@setplength{firstheadhpos}{1.0cm}                            % horizontal position of the header
  \@setplength{firstheadvpos}{1.2cm}                            % vertical position of the header
  \@setplength{firstheadwidth}{17.4cm}                          % width of the header    
  \@setplength{backaddrheight}{0pt}                         % because backaddress=off
  \@setplength{toaddrhpos}{3cm}                             %distance from left
\@setplength{toaddrindent}{0.0cm}                               %distance from top
  \@setplength{toaddrhpos}{2.7cm}                               %distance from left page edge  
 %\@setplength{toaddrheight}{3.5cm}                         %height of the addressbox toaddrhpos
 \@setplength{toaddrwidth}{7cm}                             % width of the addressbox
 %\@setplength{subjectvpos}{8cm}                                % 10cm = Betreff auf höhe Datum   
 \@setplength{subjectbeforevskip}{1cm}
\@setplength{subjectaftervskip}{1cm}
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{0.2cm}
\makeatother

% KOMA variabeln
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%\setkomavar{title}{sometitle}
\setkomavar{place}{{aplace}\setkomavar{date}{\today}}       % Datum auf linker Seite des Blattes
%\setkomavar{location}{1.Dezember 2155}                     % Datum in der locationbox (rechts)

\setkomavar{subject}{\textcolor{grau}{\bfseries Bewerbung als XY ÄÖÜ}}
\setkomavar{subjectseparator}{} % <=====================================
\renewcaptionname{german}{\subjectname}{}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\subjectname}{}

%Absenderaddresse
\setkomavar{fromname}{somebodys name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{address \\ CH-5855 Place}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{email@url.tld}
%\setkomavar{emailseparator}{~}                               %zwischen E-Mail x und adresse@url.tld
%\renewcaptionname{german}\emailname{~}
%\renewcaptionname{english}\emailname{~}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{1.png}}
%Empfängeraddresse
\setkomavar{toname}{joe publicitas}
\setkomavar{toaddress}{gehweg \\ CH-6000 Aaarau}
%Singatur
\setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{signature.png}}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
\newcommand*{\raggedsection}{\raggedright}
\newcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\raggedright}
\newcommand*{\raggedpart}{\raggedright}


% KOMA Head with 4 sections
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[b][2.5cm][t]{6cm} %{minipage}[ÄUSSERE POSITION][HÖHE][INNERE POSITION(inhalt)]{BREITE} b,c,t
    \begin{flushleft}
        \usekomavar{fromlogo}
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[b][2.5cm][t]{6cm}
    \begin{flushright}
        \begin{large}  
        \usekomavar{fromname}\\
        \end{large}    
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[b][2,55cm][t]{0.01cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[step=.5cm,black,thick] %ultra thin, very thin, thin, semithick, thick, very thick, ultra thick. gray,
        \draw
        (0,2) -- ++(0,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \centering
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[b][2.5cm][t]{3.5cm}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{large}  
        \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
            \usekomavar{fromemail}\\
        \end{large}    
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
}
}

\begin{document}

% KOMA letter 2
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{letter}{}

\opening{Sehr gegehrte Damen und Herren}

Your tenancy is due to come to an end on \today. I would like to arrange an inspection at the property before the tenancy ends to identify anything that may lead me to retain some of your deposit if not addressed by the time I retake possession.

Carrying out this inspection prior to the tenancy ending will give you the opportunity to tackle anything raised and ensure I can return the maximum amount of deposit to you when the tenancy ends

I would like to carry out the inspection on \{\{date\}\} at \{\{time\}\}. It would be best if you were present then if anything is identified we can discuss this and be clear on what would be required to rectify it. Please can you contact me as soon as possible to confirm whether or not this is convenient.

If you do not wish to be present I have a set of keys to access the property and will send you the results of the inspection. Please let me know either way at your earliest convenience.

\closing{Freundliche Grüsse}
\vspace{0.0cm}
\usekomavar{fromname}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redefining `subjectseparator` and/or `\subjectname`, you just should replace option `subject=titled` by `subject=untitled` or remove the option to get the default (see [the manual](http://www.komascript.de/scrguide) for more information about option `subject`):

```
%%Brief-Vorlage, v1.03
%%kompiliert mit LuaTeX
\documentclass[%
    fontsize=12pt,          % fontsize
    paper=a4,               % page size a4
    firsthead=on,           % display header on first page
    headsepline=false,
    fromalign=right,         % placement of name in letter head | centered,
    fromrule=false,  % separate the address with a line in letter head, false or aftername, afteraddress
    fromemail=on,          % turn on email of sender
    fromurl=off,            % print URL of sender
    fromphone=false,          % turn on phone of sender
    fromlogo=on,           % turn on logo of sender    
    fromfax=false,
    backaddress=off,
    subject=afteropening,        %beforeopening <===============================
    %subject=underlined,
    subject=untitled,         % titled
    subject=left,               % centered
    locfield=wide,          % wide, narrow
    refline=wide,               % narrow
    parskip=half,           % Use indent instead of skip, half, false
    enlargefirstpage=on,    % more space on first page
    addrfield=on,           % address field for envelope with window, on or true
    foldmarks=on,          % print foldmarks
    numericaldate=off,      % display date in numbers only
    footsepline=false,  
    firstfoot=on,           % display footer on first page
    pagenumber=botleft,         % position of the page number | botcenter,        
    draft=false
 ]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant = swiss]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant = british]{english}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Fontspec
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
%%\setmainfont{Gill Sans Light}
%%\setsansfont{Gill Sans Light}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
%%\setmonofont{Inconsolata}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
%%\setmathfont{XITS-Math}[]
%\setmathsf{}[]
%\setmathtt{}[]
%\setboldmathrm{}[]
\definecolor{grau}{rgb}{0.20,0.40,0.65}

% Development helpers
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\LoadLetterOption{SNleft} %% oder: DINmtext, SN, SNleft, KOMAold.
%\LoadLetterOption{visualize}\showfields{address,foot,head,location,refline}    % loads visualize.lco to visualize boxes
\fboxrule=0pt                                           %border thickness der fboxes zum bearbeiten auf 1 setzten

% KOMA blockgrössen
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
  \@setplength{firstheadhpos}{1.0cm}                            % horizontal position of the header
  \@setplength{firstheadvpos}{1.2cm}                            % vertical position of the header
  \@setplength{firstheadwidth}{17.4cm}                          % width of the header    
  \@setplength{backaddrheight}{0pt}                         % because backaddress=off
  \@setplength{toaddrhpos}{3cm}                             %distance from left
\@setplength{toaddrindent}{0.0cm}                               %distance from top
  \@setplength{toaddrhpos}{2.7cm}                               %distance from left page edge  
 %\@setplength{toaddrheight}{3.5cm}                         %height of the addressbox toaddrhpos
 \@setplength{toaddrwidth}{7cm}                             % width of the addressbox
 %\@setplength{subjectvpos}{8cm}                                % 10cm = Betreff auf höhe Datum   
 \@setplength{subjectbeforevskip}{1cm}
\@setplength{subjectaftervskip}{1cm}
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{0.2cm}
\makeatother

% KOMA variabeln
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%\setkomavar{title}{sometitle}
\setkomavar{place}{{aplace}\setkomavar{date}{\today}}       % Datum auf linker Seite des Blattes
%\setkomavar{location}{1.Dezember 2155}                     % Datum in der locationbox (rechts)
\addtokomafont{subject}{\color{grau}\bfseries}% color+font of the subject
\setkomavar{subject}{Bewerbung als XY ÄÖÜ}% subject variable

%Absenderaddresse
\setkomavar{fromname}{somebodys name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{address \\ CH-5855 Place}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{email@url.tld}
%\setkomavar{emailseparator}{~}                               %zwischen E-Mail x und adresse@url.tld
%\renewcaptionname{german}\emailname{~}
%\renewcaptionname{english}\emailname{~}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image}}% We do not
                                % have 1.png
%Empfängeraddresse
\setkomavar{toname}{joe publicitas}
\setkomavar{toaddress}{gehweg \\ CH-6000 Aaarau}
%Singatur
\setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{example-image}\\% we do not
                                % have signature.png
  \usekomavar{fromname}}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
\newcommand*{\raggedsection}{\raggedright}% nonsense for letters
\newcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\raggedright}% nonsense for letters
\newcommand*{\raggedpart}{\raggedright}% nonsense for letters


% KOMA Head with 4 sections
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[b][2.5cm][t]{6cm} %{minipage}[ÄUSSERE POSITION][HÖHE][INNERE POSITION(inhalt)]{BREITE} b,c,t
    \begin{flushleft}
        \usekomavar{fromlogo}
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[b][2.5cm][t]{6cm}
    \begin{flushright}
        \begin{large}  
        \usekomavar{fromname}\\
        \end{large}    
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[b][2,55cm][t]{0.01cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[step=.5cm,black,thick] %ultra thin, very thin, thin, semithick, thick, very thick, ultra thick. gray,
        \draw
        (0,2) -- ++(0,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \centering
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[b][2.5cm][t]{3.5cm}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{large}  
        \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
            \usekomavar{fromemail}\\
        \end{large}    
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
}
}

\begin{document}

% KOMA letter 2
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{letter}{}

\opening{Sehr gegehrte Damen und Herren}

Your tenancy is due to come to an end on \today. I would like to arrange an inspection at the property before the tenancy ends to identify anything that may lead me to retain some of your deposit if not addressed by the time I retake possession.

Carrying out this inspection prior to the tenancy ending will give you the opportunity to tackle anything raised and ensure I can return the maximum amount of deposit to you when the tenancy ends

I would like to carry out the inspection on \{\{date\}\} at \{\{time\}\}. It would be best if you were present then if anything is identified we can discuss this and be clear on what would be required to rectify it. Please can you contact me as soon as possible to confirm whether or not this is convenient.

If you do not wish to be present I have a set of keys to access the property and will send you the results of the inspection. Please let me know either way at your earliest convenience.

\closing{Freundliche Grüsse}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image: Subject without title]

As you can see, this just removes the subject title "Betreff:" and the space after the title.

BTW: You've had `subject=titled` twice in your option list of `\documentclass`. So you have to remove one or change both, if you try to use the above with your real letter.

Comment: Thank you. I have noticed that Subject was twice in the \documentclass already. I like to have the possiblity to add a Title and because it just does not display it i have subject=titled. If i leave it blanc its displays the letter as if it wold be untitled...

Comment: @novski: You've redefined `\subjectname` to remove "`Betreff:`" and asked how to also remove the space (of variable `subjectseparator`) after `\subjectname`. `subject=untitled` does exactly remove "Betreff:" and the separator, nothing else. So it should be exactly what you want. And `subject=untitled` is also the default. So can just remove (each occurence of) `subject=titled` to have a subject without "Betreff: ". You can still add a title to the letter using `\setkomavar{title}{Title}`. `subject=untitled` does only influence the subject title not the letter title.